# How to disable Letsencrypt on self-hosted AppSmith?

Tags: lets-encrypt, appsmith

If ssl is already being served by AWS ACM, how can I disable AppSmith's Letencrypt option? I don't see any flag on the docker.env file.

Answer (score 3):

Are you running your Appsmith instance behind a load balancer? Like an ALB? If yes, I'm guessing you have SSL termination there so you don't need SSL on the Appsmith server.

In this case, removing the `APPSMITH_CUSTOM_DOMAIN` env variable should do what you need. Without this, Appsmith won't try to provision a cert, but redirects should still work fine since ALB will share the host information to Appsmith.